# How to open and close different windows at the same time?

Tags: rebol

I'm still new to rebol and programming in general, and I'm trying to write a program for practice.

In this program, there is a main window, which includes a button with which I want to open a new window, and close the main window at the same time.

Now, I know how to do each function separately, but how do I combine them together?

This is what I tried:

```
button "Start" [view start-win unview main-win]
```

What's happening is that start-win opens when I click the button, then immediately all the windows close.

Comment: Never mind. I switched around the view and unview, and it worked. Can someone still explain it properly in an answer though? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view` starts an event loop - so no code executes after that until the window `view` opened closes.

To start a new window without that happening, use `view/new` - then to start the event loop when you are ready, `do-events`

Answer (score 1):

`unview`removes the last added window and does not take any arguments by default. To close a specific window use with refinement `unview/only window-name`
So in your first case you create a new window and next close it. In the other case you start closing the last created window and next create a new one.